# Formatting Excel Table

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have transformed data (using Power Query) in Excel from PDF and it currently looks like this (where each space represents a new column and each letter represents a different cell's data):

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Char1 | A | B | C |
| Char1 | D | E | F |
| Char1 | G | H | I |
| Char1 | J | K | L |
| Char2 | A | B | C |
| Char2 | D | E | F |
| Char2 | G | H | I |
| Char2 | J | K | L |
| Char3 | A | B | C |
| Char3 | D | E | F |
| Char3 | G | H | I |
| Char3 | J | K | L |

but I would like it to look like this:

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 | Column5 | Column6 | Column7 | Column8 | Column9 | Column10 | Column11 | Column12 | Column13 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Char1 | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L |
| Char2 | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L |
| Char3 | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L |

Any tips on how to do this?

Comment: Do any of these answers solve your issue? If so, please toggle checkmark to mark question as solved

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source , {"Column1"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", {"Column1"}, {{"data", each  Text.Combine(_[Value],","), type text}}),
Columns = List.Transform({2 .. 1+List.Max(Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "count", each List.Count(Text.PositionOfAny([data],{","},Occurrence.All))+1)[count])}, each "Column " & Text.From(_)),
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), Columns)
in #"Split Column by Delimiter"
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your response, would I add what you suggested to the Power Query before transforming or after and where would I add it?

Comment: If your data looks like my input, then eliminate the first step of what I provided, and paste in my additional steps after your steps, replacing the word Source in mine with the name of #"YourPriorStep".  You can do this in home...advanced editor...